# Как сделать игнор на регистр всех символов в строке Python?

Tags: python

Есть строка, например: `"Привет"`. Она проверяется через `if`, если это так, то значение равно `1`, иначе `0`.

Но если ввести: `"привет"` или `"привеТ"` или `"пРивет"` и т.д., то значение будет равно `0`.

Как сделать так, чтобы было игнорирование на регистр символов в строке?

Answer (score 19):

Казалось бы, можно просто взять и привести обе строки к единому регистру (верхнему или нижнему), однако всё не так просто. Бывает текст, для которого `text.lower() != text.upper().lower()`, например `"ß"`:

```
"ß".lower()
>>> 'ß'

"ß".upper().lower()
>>> 'ss'
```

Допустим, нужно сравнить `"BUSSE"` и `"Buße"`, или даже `"BUSSE"` и `"BUẞE"` — это всё считается одинаковыми словами в немецком языке. Рекомендуемый способ — использовать метод `casefold`, который преобразует строку в форму, пригодную для регистронезависимого сравнения.

```
>>> "BUSSE".casefold() == "Buße".casefold()
True
```

Но и это ещё не всё. Если у вас текст рендерится корректно, в следующем примере вы можете подумать, что `'Й' == 'Й'`, но это не так:

```
>>> 'Й' == 'Й'
False
```

Дело в том, что первый `Й` — это один символ (U+0419), а второй `Й` — комбинация из двух (U+0418 и U+0306):

```
>>> import unicodedata

>>> [unicodedata.name(char) for char in 'Й']
['CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SHORT I']

>>> [unicodedata.name(char) for char in 'Й']
['CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER I', 'COMBINING BREVE']
```

Если вам нужно считать такие строки одинаковыми, то самый простой способ справиться с этим — использовать `unicodedata.normalize`. Вероятно, вам стоит использовать нормализацию **[NFKD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#NFKD)**, но [документация предлагает и другие варианты](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize); можете выбрать то, что подходит для вашей задачи. Тогда:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'Й') == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'Й')
True
```

Объединив это всё, вы можете использовать вот такие функции:

```
import unicodedata

def normalize_caseless(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text.casefold())

def caseless_equal(left, right):
    return normalize_caseless(left) == normalize_caseless(right)


>>> caseless_equal('BUSSE', 'Buße')
True

>>> caseless_equal('Й', 'Й')
True
```

---

<sup>*Вольный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/5418360) от [Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac) с enSO. Там есть полезные комментарии, можно их тоже почитать.*</sup>

Comment: У меня есть такой скрипт, который даёт ответ на написанное слово(проще говоря, чат-бот для ВКонтакте). Допустим, если пользователь напишет слово: "привеТ" или напишет абсолютно любую заглавную букву боту, то бот её не примет, т.к. у него в скрипте идёт проверка именно по слову "Привет". Данный Ваш скрипт поможет ли в решении этой проблемы?

Comment: @ANDROSHA ну если вы грамотно внедрите caseless_equal в свой скрипт, то поможет

Comment: про сравнение строк с учётом нормализации в  Unicode уже придуманы алгоритмы, к примеру, [D145](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551443/4279)

Comment: В общем, я нашёл другое решение данной ситуации. "Регулярные выражения". Только недавно о них узнал и с ними оказалось всё проще)

Comment: @ANDROSHA регулярные выражения не решают ни одной из проблем, описанных здесь, так что они - неправильное решение

Comment: @andreymal точнее не регулярные выражения, а метод re.findall('слово', usertext, flags=re.INGORECASE). Просто он поддерживает регулярные выражения и привык называть его так.

Comment: @ANDROSHA это не отменяет того, что findall не решает ни одной из описанных здесь проблем

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали выше, можно добавить .casefold к переменной:

```
dic = {"Hello": "Здравствуй", "Bye": "Пока", "Lesson": "Урок"}
arr1 = int(random.random() * 3)
key2 = list(dic.keys())
key3 = list(dic.values())
while True:
    arr1 = int(random.random() * 3)
    print("Введите перевод :", key2[arr1])
    z = input()
    x = key3[arr1]
    if z.casefold() == x.casefold():
        print("Перевод верный!")
        continue
    if z.casefold() == str("show"):
        print(dic)
        continue
    if z.casefold() == str("quit"):
        exit()
    else:
        print("Вы ввели неверный перевод!")
        continue
```