# Как сделать чтоб if не реагировал если текст написан с большой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

чисто для примера вот такой код:

```
if a == "привет":
    print ("привет")
```

но если `а` будет равняться не `привет` а `Привет` это не сработает, как можно сделать так чтоб if не реагировал на то большие ли буквы или нет

Comment: можно добавить elif и в нем написать ``Привет`` но это не удобно и не практично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приводите символы строки к нижнему регистру методом [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).

***Пример:***

```py
a = 'Привет'

if a.lower() == 'привет':
    print('привет')  # привет
```

Comment: Есть способ лучше — см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858202/339283) от участника [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/) в аналогичном вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

попробуй через lower

```
example = "ПриВеТ"
if example.lower() == "привет":
    print("привет")
```

Comment: чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа который дал участник nomnoms12?

Comment: Я его не увидел, простите)

Comment: вы можете удалить свой ответ с помощью ссылки "удалить" ниже текста ответа.